# Convert String to arraylist using split

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, jsoup

Is it possible to convert below String content to an arraylist using [split](http://programming.guide/java/split-string-into-arraylist.html), so that you get something like in point A?

```
<a class="postlink" href="http://test.site/i7xt1.htm">http://test.site/i7xt1.htm<br/>
</a>
<br/>Mirror:<br/>
<a class="postlink" href="http://information.com/qokp076wulpw">http://information.com/qokp076wulpw<br/>
</a>
<br/>Additional:<br/>
<a class="postlink" href="http://additional.com/qokdsfsdwulpw">http://additional.com/qokdsfsdwulpw<br/>
</a>
```

**Point A** (desired arraylist content):

```
http://test.site/i7xt1.htm
Mirror:
http://information.com/qokp076wulpw
Additional:
http://additional.com/qokdsfsdwulpw
```

I am now using below code but it doesn`t bring the desired output. (mirror for instance is being added multiple times etc).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(string);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
    Node previousSibling = link.previousSibling();

    while (!(previousSibling.nodeName().equals("u") || previousSibling.nodeName().equals("#text"))) {
        previousSibling = previousSibling.previousSibling();
    }

    String identifier = previousSibling.toString();

    if (identifier.contains("Mirror")) {
        totalUrls.add("MIRROR(s):");
    }
    totalUrls.add(link.attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to split a string, or how to populate an ArrayList?

Comment: Could you try to format the HTML a little nicer?

Comment: Hi shmosel, my goal is to get the content of the String into an arraylist like in point A. I thought using split was the easiest way to do it but I can be wrong.

Comment: Ok, but what are you stuck on?

Comment: I hope it`s better now cricket_007

Comment: @shmosel, I don`t know how to use split for my needs, maybe it can also be done with jsoup but I do not now what is more efficient.
As mentioned my code now produces duplicate "Mirror" entries in the arraylist.

Comment: JSoup may be able to do something with that, but here's a crude regex. https://regex101.com/r/uI3P3w/1

Comment: @cricket_007, the thing is also, the only surtain content between the <br/> brackets I know is "Mirror:", what text is present in the <br/> brackets after that can be anything. I just took "additonal" now as an example.

Comment: The regular expression doesn't care what is in between anything. It just grabs `<br/>some text<br/>` if exists, then the next `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your links first.  As cricket_007 mentioned, having proper HTML would make this a lot easier.

```
String html = yourHtml.replaceAll("<br/></a>", "</a>"); // get rid of bad HTML
String[] lines = html.split("<br/>");

for (String str : Arrays.asList(lines)) {
    Jsoup.parse(str).text();
    ... // you can go further here, check if it has a link or not to display your semi-colon;
}
```

Now that the errant `<br>` tags are out of the links, you can split the string on the `<br>` tags that remain and print out your html result.  It's not pretty, but it should work.

Comment: I noticed that hyperlinks (<a href="http://info.to/uijtwf">Information</a>) are not clickable anymore and don`t open. Can that be corrected? Normal links are working well.

Comment: You're missing http:// at the beginning of your link in that given example (href="info.to..."). That's making a relative link to your own website directory.